# document.location.hash equals ID name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make some actions depends on window hash, go to `div id` anchors.

```
<div id="#A1"></div>
<div id="#A2"></div>
<div id="#A3"></div>
<div id="#A4"></div>
......
<div id="#B1"></div>
```

and jS

```
    function myWay(){
    //do something  
    }

    if(document.location.hash == "A1"){
             myWay();   
    }
    if(document.location.hash == "A2"){
             myWay();   
    }
    if(document.location.hash == "A3"){
             myWay();   
    }
    .......
```

my question is that, if I have more than 30 anchors, I have to put over 30 `if(document.location.hash == "#anchor")` on my JavaScript. Is there a way to search and match do something like

```
if (document.location.hash == (this anchor on the page)){
         myWay();
}else{
    something else;
}
```

Comment: olo, what is "existing" in this context?

Comment: I'm confused. Changing the location.hash should *automatically* scroll to the same ID. Why do you need JS to do it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case since your IDs match a specific pattern, use a regex:

```
if (document.location.hash.match(/[A-C][1-4]/)) { ... }
```

It will match A, B, or C followed by a number from 1 to 4.

If your IDs don't have a pattern, try using a loop:

```
var ids = ['valid', 'ids', 'etc...'], valid = false;
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i ++) {
    if (yourId === ids[i]) valid = true;
}
if (valid) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so the anchors cannot be named randomly?

Comment: @olo See my edit: If they don't have a pattern, just use a loop and an array.

Comment: indexOf would work instead of the loop [use polyfill for browsers that do not support it[

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple array:

```
arr = ["A1","A2", /* ... */ "Z9"];
if ($.inArray(location.hash, arr) > -1) { 
// or use arr.indexOf(location.hash) if you don't care about old browsers
   myWay();
};
```